# Jenkins Workspace structure

Tags: ios, svn, jenkins

I have a project for iOS which I am trying to make it a part of a Continuos Integration. Apparently, every time I try to compile the project it gives me an error of cannot locate the file.

The structure of the entire directory is as following

ABC/test2/Feed/xcodeproject.xcodespace

So hence in SVN my url is as following:

www.company.com/trunk/

where after trunk the entire directory of ABC gets downloaded, and the structure of the application is correct. However when I am trying to build the application

> xcodebuild ARCHS=i386 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -target "ABC" -configuration
>   Release -sdk iphonesimulator

Now the content of ABC project is lying within /ABC/test2/Feed/ directory, hence the error is generated is The directory "xyz" does not contain an Xcode project.

If I go another approach using svn as www.company.com/trunk/ABC/test2/Feed/
then some files within the structure doesn't lays correctly and says the files are missing and fails to build.

How can I fix the first scenario which I bet is the easier fix for all of this in Jenkins Configure?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your issue, but I will take a stab at it. It sounds like your xcodebuild command is looking for the project in the current directory, which is always the workspace root by default. You should be able to resolve this by inserting the following in the Jenkins project shell before calling the project: "cd ./ABC/test2/Feed". This changes the current directory to the location of the xcode project.

Comment: @CIGuy, this is so silly of me, I should have done the cd option. Lol over looked the shell execution stuff, completely forgot that thats shell execution. Thanks so much for the update.

Comment: Glad I could help. You would be amazed how many people run into this issue when using Jenkins.